# Twisted share a variable between tcp/udp protocols

Tags: python, twisted

I have the following tcpserver simple example. I'm looking to share the factor counter var with a udp server so on each connect it will inc the value for both tcp and udp. So if i connect first with tcp it will be 2 then if I connect to the port on udp.. it will be 3

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory, Protocol
from twisted.internet import reactor

class TCP(Protocol):

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.factory.counter += 1
        self.transport.write(str(self.factory.counter)+'\r\n')
        self.transport.loseConnection()

class QOTDFactory(Factory):

    def __init__(self, protocol='tcp'):
        if protocol == 'tcp':
            self.protocol = TCP
        else:
            self.protocol = UDP

        self.counter = 1

reactor.listenTCP(8007, QOTDFactory('tcp'))
#reactor.listenUDP(8007, QOTDFactory('udp'))

reactor.run()
```

My main issue is starting up a UDP class that will work along side.. that is my sticking point. I think how i reference the counter is ok and will work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argument to `reactor.listenUDP` should be a `DatagramProtocol` instance, as shown in the UDP example: http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/udp.html.  You can't use your `QOTDFactory` with UDP, so it doesn't need the TCP vs UDP selection logic.  Instead, just make a `DatagramProtocol` subclass with your desired protocol logic and let it share a reference to the factory used by your TCP server.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory, Protocol
from twisted.internet import reactor

class StreamCounter(Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        self.factory.counter += 1
        self.transport.write(str(self.factory.counter)+'\r\n')
        self.transport.loseConnection()


class DatagramCounter(DatagramProtocol):
    def __init__(self, factory):
        self.factory = factory

    def datagramReceived(self, data, address):
        self.factory.counter += 1
        self.transport.write(str(self.factory.counter), address)


class QOTDFactory(Factory):
    counter = 0
    protocol = StreamCounter


factory = QOTDFactory()
reactor.listenTCP(8007, factory)
reactor.listenUDP(8007, DatagramCounter(factory))

reactor.run()
```

I renamed `TCP` and `UDP` to `StreamCounter` and `DatagramCounter`, since they're not limited to use with TCP and UDP respectively (and those weren't terrible descriptive names ;).  For example, you'll be able to use `StreamCounter` over SSL using `reactor.listenSSL` as well.

Comment: How is the DatagramCounter sharing a reference to the factor used by the TCP server?

Comment: Excellent question!  My answer was actually wrong.  I forgot to add the part that hooks the DatagramCounter up to the factory.  Edited answer with the fix.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for your needs?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory, Protocol
from twisted.internet import reactor

class Counter():
  def __init__(self):
    self.count = 0

class TCP(Protocol):

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.factory.counter.count += 1
        self.transport.write(str(self.factory.counter)+'\r\n')
        self.transport.loseConnection()

class QOTDFactory(Factory):

    def __init__(self, protocol, counter):
        if protocol == 'tcp':
            self.protocol = TCP
        else:
            self.protocol = UDP

        self.counter = counter

counter = Counter()
reactor.listenTCP(8007, QOTDFactory('tcp', counter))
reactor.listenUDP(8007, QOTDFactory('udp', counter))

reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [static class variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68672/672848) to implement this counter:

```
class QOTDFactory(Factory):
    counter = 1

    def __init__(self, protocol='tcp'):
        if protocol == 'tcp':
            self.protocol = TCP
        else:
            self.protocol = UDP

        QOTDFactory.counter += 1
```

Comment: Sorry maybe the question was worded wrong.. but i think my self.counter is ok in how i reference it in the tcp class.. my issue is starting up another UDP class based off that factory

Comment: Ok. But honestly I still don't understand. Could you be a bit more precise in formulating the question?! What _exactly_ is the issue you are stuck on?